# Setting scaladoc header/footer in Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle, scaladoc

I'm not sure how to set `ScalaDoc` options in Gradle, but it appears possible because I see that Gradle has [ScalaDoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/scala/ScalaDoc.html) and [ScalaDocOptions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/scala/ScalaDocOptions.html). ScalaDocOptions has a `setFooter`, which I am interested in calling.

How do I use these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code should work:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1'
}

project.tasks.scaladoc.scalaDocOptions.footer = 'lol'
```

but it doesn't since gradle under the hood calls ant which does not support this attribute.

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/39088691) you have a demo. Run it with `gradle scaladoc -s` to see where the problem lies.

However this answer in general shows how you can configure task's options and attributes.

Comment: There's an answer for SBT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996651/is-there-a-way-to-include-math-formulae-in-scaladoc/32114551#32114551